# Remove duplicate(?) linux image

Tags: grub

When I configuring grub, I found out that I have multiple linux image, like this
[image: grub configure]

I checked with `uname -r` command, it showed `4.15.0-62-generic`.

And then I checked on my `/boot` directory with `ls -l`, and the result is
[image: boot directory]

The question is:

1. Do I have multiple linux (Elementary OS) ?
2. And if so, How to remove the duplicate ?
3. Why when i checked with uname -r it's not showing the latest version (...-62-...) instead of (...-64-...) ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unusual for kernel upgrade procedures to leave old kernels and attendant ramdisks and system maps in `/boot` after installing new ones.  This allows grub to be used to select a different kernel if the kernel upgrade fails.  if you looked at your grub config you'd probably see that the default is whatever kernel you're running , but there's other entries you don't see when you boot that are the older kernels.

Typically, you can mix and match kernels fairly successfully.  So if your new kernel failed to work or some reason, you could boot off an old kernel and everything would probably work.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, It's clear now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an image for some reason (botched install, won't boot, ...) just use your regular uninstall command, *giving the full version*. That tool does understand how to delete the kernel (and any ancilliary files, fixing configuration to match), it is used behind the scenes when installing a new kernel. There should be a knob to frob for the number of kernels to keep around, Fedora keeps three -- that works out fine.